# how to get dynamic metadata in access logs with envoy

Tags: envoyproxy

I want to set some metadatas in routes config, and get them in access logs. where I have known the function is https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/4862.

however, I can't figure out how to write the yaml file, I have tried many times, but it not works.

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 10000 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          tracing:
              operation_name: ingress
          use_remote_address: true
          add_user_agent: true
          generate_request_id: true
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/trace/1" }
                route: { cluster: some_serviceA }
                metadata:
                    filter_metadata:
                        envoy.http_connection_manager.access_log:
                            test: "this is metadata"
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.http_grpc_access_log
            config:
                common_config:
                  grpc_service:
                    envoy_grpc:
                        cluster_name: accesslog_cluster
                  log_name: accesslog
  clusters:
  - name: some_serviceA
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    type: STATIC
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 127.0.0.1, port_value: 5001 }}]
  - name: accesslog_cluster
    connect_timeout: 2s
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: 127.0.0.1
        port_value: 18090
    http2_protocol_options: {}
```

But I get nothing from common metadata.

Is there an example to set the metadata into access log?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 1.9.0? https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.9.0/intro/version_history#id1

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Metadata can be set by filters using the StreamInfo API (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/2e8ddf3f1821816bfb6ae93352fcc5dcddbb058f/include/envoy/stream_info/stream_info.h): setDynamicMetadata.

You can also use Lua to set it: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/lua_filter#config-http-filters-lua-stream-info-dynamic-metadata-wrapper

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)